# How to tell whether value is NaN without using isNaN, which has false positives?

Tags: javascript, numbers, nan

How can I check whether the input value is `NaN` or not without using the `isNaN` function?

Comment: Why would you need this? Plus, this is very a much "give me the codez" demand, so ... no, we won't help.

Comment: I have a screw I need screwed in, but I don't want to use a screw driver. No, I won't tell you why I won't use a screwdriver. Let me know, thanks.

Comment: Is this homework?  I can't think of any other reason you'd want to hand role an `isNaN` function.

Comment: Here's how `isNaN` works under the hood: http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.4.  Work from there.

Comment: @asawyer: Have you tried using a hammer?

Answer (score 8):

If you can use [ECMAScript 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Harmony.2C_6th_Edition), you have [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is):

```
return Object.is(obj, NaN);
```

---

Otherwise, here is one option, from the source code of [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isNaN):

```
// Is the given value `NaN`?
_.isNaN = function(obj) {
  // `NaN` is the only value for which `===` is not reflexive.
  return obj !== obj;
};
```

Also their note for that function:

> Note: this is not the same as the native isNaN function, which will also return true if the variable is undefined.

Comment: `isNaN('0') === false`, while `_.isNaN('0')` is true.

Comment: `isNaN('as')` is `true`, but `_.isNaN('as')` is `false`.

Comment: @RobW In what? That's a bug per spec. Per spec the only thing not strictly equal to itself is NaN.

Comment: @RobW - I'm not seeing that. Rocket - that's a shame `:/`. It depends what the op is after though - it is possible s/he is looking to avoid exactly this behavior.

Comment: Why does underscore make their own `isNaN`, what's the point of that?

Comment: @Rocket - They probably want a function that checks for NaN and nothing else, as the comment says. (`isNaN(undefined) === true`)

Comment: Ah.  It seems `_.isNaN` only checks to see if the value is *literally* `NaN`.  It doesn't actually check if the value is a number or not.  This returns `true` only if the value is *actually* `NaN`, not just if something that cannot be converted to a number (like the built-in `isNaN`), they should really have explained that.

Comment: @Rocket - excellent point, it depend on what the OP wants...  I would say the question is poorly specified, but I *guessed* this could help.

Comment: @Kobi: I didn't know that `NaN === NaN` was `false`, that's weird.

Comment: @Rocket `NaN` is never equal to itself: `var x = NaN;x==x; /*false!*/`. http://jsfiddle.net/R6xpz/

Comment: @RobW: That makes no sense `X_X`

Comment: `isNaN(NaN)` is `true`, so I still don't know why this `_.isNaN` is necessary.

Comment: @Rocket - is isn't *necessary* - it is *useful*, if you want to make sure your value is `NaN`, and not `undefined`, `"Hello World"`, or other.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the input to a number, and check whether the substraction is not zero:

```
var x = 'value';
var is_NaN = +x - x !== 0; // The + is actually not needed, but added to show
                           // that a number conversion is made.
```

Comment: @Kobi: `Infinity-Infinity` is `NaN` :-P

Comment: @Kobi `isNaN(Infinity)` returns `false`, and my method returns true. Infinity is not a [real number](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Real_number), so I believe that my implementation is better (feel free to dispute me).

Comment: Rob - That's cool. Just pointed out an edge case. As long as you've thought about that, it's ok `:)`