# Is there a JavaScript alternative to isNaN()?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript logic for isNaN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094738/javascript-logic-for-isnan)

Hey all I want is to check that the entered value in a textbox is not a number or without using the function `isNaN();`. Is there any way?

Comment: Perhaps a Regular Expression?

Comment: @MikeChristensen how would I use that regular expression to check for that?

Comment: @David - Well you can look for a valid number (numeric digits, optionally a decimal point) and then return false if it does not match that expression.  However, I'd agree this question appears to be a dupe.  The linked post has some good ideas as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parseFloat(value)!== +value;
```

But what is wrong with isNaN(value)?

Comment: because js's native is not comfortable for everyone... try it: var a = NaN,b = Number("xy"); console.log(Number("asdf") == Number("asdf"),Number("try") === Number("try"),isNaN(Number("but, this is NaN :S")),typeof Number("but, this is NaN :S"),isNaN(NaN),isNaN(a),isNaN(b),a === b,a==b,b == NaN)