# How to test whether something is identically NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

In Javascript:

```
NaN === NaN; // false
```

I was trying to determine when `isNaN(foo)` is not just equivalent to `+foo` "is" `NaN`.  But I don't know how to tell if something is `NaN` except by using `isNaN`, which says yes for many things, none of which `===` NaN.

So I think the right way to do this would be to work around other possibilities:

```
typeof NaN === 'number' // true
```

Therefore I think

```
typeof(foo) === 'number' && isNaN(foo)
```

Is the closest to what I am thinking of.  It makes sense since it makes sense that `NaN` would be the only number that isn't a number, or something.  Is this correct, and is this the best way?

Comment: This'll help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094738/javascript-logic-for-isnan

Comment: True. I've voted to re-open the old one for now but sometimes these things can take a while..

Comment: @djechlin: I closed it as a duplicate of this, since this one is more informative, yes. If someone fixes the other one (since the OP appears to be long gone), it can be switched around if they like =)

Comment: @minitech right, mod powers, thanks. 3 votes away from a dupe circle...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use that to your advantage:

```
foo !== foo
```

This is equivalent to `typeof foo === 'number' && isNaN(foo)`, and [is what Underscore.js uses to check for exactly `NaN`, too](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#isNaN).

Comment: oh right, I read multiple times that `NaN` is the only value that isn't equal to itself.

Comment: both side, foo will have same value. Then what's the significance to compare?

Answer (score 3):

The reason that NaN isn't equal to itself is that two calculations can become NaN for different reasons. If you do two calculations and compare the results, you don't want them to be equal if one of the values are NaN, or both of them.

The `isNaN` method works fine as long as you only use it on numerical values. It gives unintuitive results for a lot of other types, so you simply shouldn't use it on anything other than numbers.

Comment: Does this answer the question, though? (The code says specifically “if this is a numerical value”, e.g.)

Comment: @minitech: Yes, that part of the question was added after I answered it, and this answer confirms that the result of `isNaN` only makes sense for numerical values.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [ECMAScript 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Harmony.2C_6th_Edition), you have [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is):

```
return Object.is(foo, NaN);
```

> `Object.is()` determines whether two values are the same value. Two values are the same if one of the following holds:
> [...]
>
> - both `NaN`

MDN also suggests a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Polyfill) if `Object.is` isn't defined (uses the same `foo!==foo` trick):

```
if (!Object.is) {
  Object.is = function(x, y) {
    // SameValue algorithm
    if (x === y) { // Steps 1-5, 7-10
      // Steps 6.b-6.e: +0 != -0
      return x !== 0 || 1 / x === 1 / y;
    } else {
      // Step 6.a: NaN == NaN
      return x !== x && y !== y;
    }
  };
}
```